# Decoding remote JSON into custom struct in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, json, swift, codable

I can't seem to decode the json results in the custom structs. I've included the code below, along with the JSON results.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Result: Decodable {
    public var result: [DrilledResults]
}

struct DrilledResults: Decodable {
    public var name: String
}

public class Services: ObservableObject {
    @Published var shows = [Result]()
    @Published var query = "hello"

    init() {
        load()
    }

    func load() {
        let apiKey = "ajkjshfsdkljflksdjflkdsfjf"
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/tv?api_key=\(apiKey)&language=en-US&page=1&query=\(query)&include_adult=false") else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            do {
                if let d = data {
                    let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode(Result.self, from: d)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.shows = [decoded]
                    }
                } else {
                print("No Data")
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }

        }
        .resume()
    }
}
```

Here is the json...

{
        "page": 1,
        "total_results": 101,
        "total_pages": 6,
        "results": [
            {
                "original_name": "Johnny Test",
                "genre_ids": [
                    16,
                    35
                ],
                "name": "Johnny Test",
                "popularity": 13.185,
                "origin_country": [
                    "CA",
                    "US"
                ],
                "vote_count": 49,
                "first_air_date": "2005-09-17",
                "backdrop_path": null,
                "original_language": "en",
                "id": 1769,
                "vote_average": 5.1,
                "overview": "Young Johnny is gung-ho and full of courage. Johnny's brainiac twin sisters, Susan and Mary, use Johnny as their guinea pig for their outrageous scientific experiments. If they can dream it up, Johnny will do it; as long as his genetically engineered super dog, Dukey, can come along.",
                "poster_path": null
            },
            {
                "original_name": "Bäst i test",
                "id": 71761,
                "name": "Bäst i test",
                "popularity": 3.364,
                "vote_count": 2,
                "vote_average": 4,
                "first_air_date": "2017-03-10",
                "poster_path": "/s0sERZMWn8f9J3TccGb09hEV3HW.jpg",
                "genre_ids": [
                    35
                ],
                "original_language": "sv",
                "backdrop_path": "/ammCpFm1kZ2d4KWXXhsjzBPsea7.jpg",
                "overview": "Swedish version of Taskmaster.",
                "origin_country": [
                    "SE"
                ]
            }
    ]
    }

I've tried so many combinations of the struct formats, but i've been failing for hours. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Swift struct needs to match your JSON, which it doesn't.

You can see that the outer object has a property called `results` which is an array.  Your struct has `result` - no 's'.

```
struct Result: Decodable {
    public var results: [DrilledResults]
}
```

Now, you will be able to retrieve the data, and you can clean up `self.shows` - Instead of declaring it as an array of `Results`, you can declare it as an array of `DrilledResults` and just say

```
self.shows = decoded.results
```

Answer (score 1):

Put an 's' after result.

```
struct Result: Decodable {
    public var results: [DrilledResults]
}
```